# NSOutlineView not refreshing/displaying all content

Tags: objective-c, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview

I have an NSOutlineView, with its content bound to an appropriate NSTreeController. It works perfectly well, except when my app loads, only about half of the content of the NSOutlineView displays.

If I cmd+tab away and back, all the content displays. If I click the blank rows where I know there should be content, the text in the row I clicked suddenly appears. So the content's there, it's just not refreshing properly. I guess I need to send the NSOutlineView a needsDisplay message or something similar, but I'm not quite sure where.

This seems pretty illogical to me - the NSOutlineView should surely be able to display its content properly when bound. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to the apple documentation, you should always send `-reloadData` to the outline view after it's been created.  In your case that would be wherever your NIB has finished loading (`-awakeFromNib`? `-applicationDidFinishLaunching`? Depends on the implementation).

Have you sent the outline view a `-reloadData` message?  This always works for me.

Comment: This doesn't work - the documentation here is referring to when the NSOutlineView is using a datasource, not a binding. I don't believe objects using data bindings ever need to have reloadData called on them, due to their use of Key-Value-Observing.

Comment: Ah yes of course, I've not used an outline view with cocoa bindings before.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on binding this NSOutlineView and switched to using an NSOutlineViewDataSource instead. I suspect some part of my code wasn't fully KVO compliant and this was making it not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

When using KVO, you can cause change notifications by sending [`willChangeValueForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/willChangeValueForKey%3a) and [`didChangeValueForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/didChangeValueForKey%3a) to the object (most likely a controller) that owns the property that's bound to the NSOutlineView. These messages can be sent from an `awakeFromNib:` or `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` handler, just like `reloadData`.

If you add (minimal) [sample code](http://sscce.org/) to your question, we might be able to figure out whether that will fix the problem, or whether there's something else that needs addressing.